# Excel function: Split string into horizontal Array by delimiter

Tags: arrays, excel

this time I did find a solution for my problem in here already but I could not figure out how to use it.

So basically I want to convert strings like

"aa#b#ccc#1#2"

into a horizontal array like

```
{aa.b.ccc.1.2}
```

to use them later on with Sumproduct. So this article seems to do the job:

[Split a string (cell) in Excel without VBA (e.g. for array formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula)

In there I found the formula:

```
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",""))+1)))=1),99))
```

However this will return an vertical array like:

```
{aa;b;ccc;1;2}
```

When I combine this with Sumproduct like

```
Sumproduct((a5:a10)*(b5:b10=ABOVE FORMULA))
```

I only get the sum of "aa" but not the rest. I tried transpose(ABOVE FORMULA) but it did not do the job.

Can you help me out?

Many greetings,
Peter

PS: another problem is that my numbers become strings but this is something I can handle

PPS: {aa.b.ccc.1.2} This type of array is what I see when I press F9 on the formula "{=b1:f1"}

Comment: Transpose will certainly transform it into a horizontal array. So the problem lies elsewhere.  Add a table to your question showing the contents of `a5:b10` so we may reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ISNUMBER(MATCH()) instead:

```
Sumproduct((a5:a10)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(b5:b10&"",ABOVE FORMULA,0))))
```

Even with SUMPRODUCT, you need to use Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Edit:

A slightly shorter and less volatile version of your formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))
```

so in total:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A10)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B5:B10&"",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),0))))
```

And use Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

As you can see, we are passing the vertical array to the MATCH:

[image]

Which results in the proper array of TRUE/FALSE to pass to SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott,
well done and thank you. Also, thank you for the very detailed explanations.
Now my excel sheet is filled with tons of formula and references already and I fear that my excel sheet will become too complicated and too slow if I use this method extensively to spare me some arrays. Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986075/excel-function-reference-to-array-in-cell and check if such a style can reference to arrays?