# Excel function: reference to array in cell

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an array in cell A1 via

```
A1 = {=G6:J6} = {"aa"."b"."ccc".1}
```

Now I want to use the cell A1 for array formula in B1. Basically B1 should be

```
B1 = SUMPRODUKT((C6:C12)*(B6:B12=G6:J6))
```

But instead of the direct reference to G6:J6 I would like to use A1 instead. I just tried:

```
B1 = SUMPRODUKT((C6:C12)*(B6:B12=A1))
B1 =  {=SUMPRODUKT((C6:C12)*(B6:B12=A1))}
```

But this would not work. Is there a way to make it work?

Greetings,
Peter

For questions that appeared:

Cells G6:J6 are input data for example article numbers. I want to setup the input data only once in my sheet so I have to update less data. entries in G6:J6 are strings or numbers. Let's say G6 = "aa", H6 = "b", I6 = "ccc" and J6 = 1.

Cell B1 is one point where I need to use the data. It would rather be in another sheet but for simpler examples let's assume it is cell B1. In B1 I could of course refer to G6:J6 but this makes formular less easy to read. Therefore I would like to put a reference A1 next to B1 so one can see easily what data B1 uses.

C6:C12 is some numbers and B6:B12 is some strings/numbers that maybe match G6:J6. So sumproduct should sumup the matches.

Comment: What is the idea of the Sumproduct? What is `B6:B12=A1`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet and expected results? from your question, its not clear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell A1 contains an array formula or array range but it only contains a single value from that array or range (each Excel cell can only contain a single result value).

So you need to replace the A1 in your SUMPRODUCT with an array or range expression.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Or must I always refer to the original array?

Comment: There are no simple workarounds: best answer is always to use the original array/range

Answer (score 0):

Cell `A1` value shall be `G6:J6`

G6:J6 populated as required with `{"aa","bb","ccc",1}` then in `B1` put following formula and check if this is what you need.

`=SUMPRODUCT(C6:C12*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B6:B12,INDIRECT(A1))))`

Comment: Hi, I will check if this gives me the result. However, I think it will be best to simply refer to the original range. It must be much faster than your result.