# Counting the repeating values in comma-separated lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data in column A has comma-separated values (one/two digit numbers).
I need a way to count the number of repeats in two consecutive rows.

Example data:

```
DATA              Expected Results
1,2,3,4,5                4
2,3,4,5                  2
3,4                      0
10,11,40,60,72,75        3
10,40,3,75
```

Note that each list doesn't have the same number of values. A1 has 5 values, A2 has 4, A3 has 2, etc.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to using a User Defined Function (VBA)?

Comment: I prefer a formula if possible. but I'm open to vba too. I know this is a little complicated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option for `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))=(TRANSPOSE(1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))))),"")
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

[image]

Picture shows dots as I couldn't use commas due to my version of Excel.

Borrowed some knowledge from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933311/excel-function-split-string-into-horizontal-array-by-delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

as a VBA alternative

```
Public Function commonCount(aRng As Range, bRng As Range) As Integer
Dim bArr() As String, aArr() As String, a As Integer, b As Integer

aArr = Split(aRng.Value, ",")
bArr = Split(bRng.Value, ",")

For a = LBound(aArr) To UBound(aArr)
    For b = LBound(bArr) To UBound(bArr)
        If aArr(a) = bArr(b) Then
            commonCount = commonCount + 1
            GoTo nexta
        End If
    Next b
nexta:
Next a

End Function
```

In B2 `commonCount(A2,A3)`