# Dynamic OR criteria for SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula like below

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$AK:$AK,'Sheet1'!$AL:$AL,"<=0",'Sheet1'!$N:$N,C2))
```

I want the C2 to be a dynamic multiple criteria OR field which might range from 1 to 4 criteria.

If it would have been static the formula would be something like below

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$AK:$AK,'Sheet1'!$AL:$AL,"<=0",'Sheet1'!$N:$N,{"262","261","200"}))
```

How do I do it ? I can't get it to work with {"262","261","200"} as value in C2.

The below doesn't work either after having different values in C2,C3,C4

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$AK:$AK,'Sheet1'!$AL:$AL,"<=0",'Sheet1'!$N:$N,{C2,C3,C4}))
```

Comment: OR conditions in a SUMIFS criteria need to be hard-coded; you cannot use a cell or range reference or formula to evaluate them. I would humbly suggest a UDF that can perform this sort of dynamic criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$AK:$AK,Sheet1!$AL:$AL,"<=0",Sheet1!$N:$N,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C2, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")))
```

Credit to [Vafā Sarmast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47266679/6241235) for splitting to array technique.

It seems, from using evaluate formula, that the numbers end up being enclosed in `<s>` tags, which are then used via xpath of `//s`, to return all matching items as a list i.e. the numbers as an array. To insert the tags substitute is used on the existing delimiter along with concatenation (`& "</s></t>"`). At least, that is my understanding.

Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as array formula.

Values go in as comma separated in C2

[image: Formula]

Info:

[FILTERXML](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/filterxml-function.htm)

Comment: It worked now. Forgot that it's supposed to be an array formula

Comment: Enter as array formula and let me know. Seems to work at my end.

Comment: Hello again, how to get it to work for INDEX-MATCH ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula. `SUMIFS()` supports multiple criteria so you can user `C2`, `C3`, `C4` as criteria.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$AK:$AK,Sheet1!$AL:$AL,"<=0",Sheet1!$N:$N,C2,Sheet1!$N:$N,C3,Sheet1!$N:$N,C4))
```

Comment: That would be AND criteria I guess, not OR criteria