# SUMPRODUCT with duplicate values in Dropdown in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with multiple dropdown selection, where items are binded with master data in sheet 2. Master data contains items and their respective values.
Now I am using a formula for sum of items selected in the dropdown list as below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(PRODUCT,J4))*AMOUNT)
```

where PRODUCT & AMOUNT is master data and J4 is column reference of multiple selection dropdown list.
Code works well but whenever I select duplicate item in dropdown list the amount of duplicate item is not reflected in the SUM column where the code is addedd. However the count of items selected works well with below formula

```
=IF(J4="","",(LEN(J4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(J4,CHAR(10),""))+1))
```

Data:

[image: data]

```
| PRODUCT | AMOUNT |
|---------|--------|
| Apple   | 100    |
| Grapes  | 200    |
| Orange  | 50     |
| Mango   | 500    |
| Guava   | 350    |
| Cherry  | 170    |
```

Expected result:

It's multiple selection dropdown. In second row I have selected Apple, Grapes & Orange so it counts 350 (100 + 200 + 50). Now in 1st row if I select Apple again then the cost of apple should be added in sum i.e. it should be 450 (100 + 200 + 50 + 100)

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: @QHarr Image added for more description

Comment: Where is J4 in all of this? Is it the products column on the left?

Comment: And how does Apples end up at 350, even if only once, as value is 100 on right hand side? A bit more explanation would help.

Comment: Its multiple selection dropdown. In second row I have selected Apple, Grapes & Orange so it counts 350 (100 + 200 + 50). Now in 1st row if I select Apple two times then the sum should be Apple, Grapes, Orange & Apple 450 (100 + 200 + 50 + 100). I think it clears the doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

**Generic:**

You want a generic formula of:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(PRODUCT,array,AMOUNT))
```

**Specific example:**

For top box e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(PRODUCT,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"),AMOUNT))
```

Based on your file:

[image: Data]

Note I use `FILTERXML` to create the array of values from the drop down selection. `Char(10)` is for your new line.

See my explanation of FILTERML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50363250/6241235).

---

**Example run:**

[image: Example]

Comment: The column reference is J4 where multiple dropdown are located. So E3:E6 replaced with J4 but it shows sum as zero (0). J4 is single cell where we can select multiple items in dropdown and displays in new line But the cell remains single.

Comment: J4 is single cell with items with new line (vbNewLine)

Comment: Please see I have uploaded the excel some column hided pass if asked is 'test' https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp5evikosfctp9o/Book2%20-%20Copy.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: No its not working, when I select item form dropdown the value is showing 0. I dont know I have missed something

Comment: Yes it was correct. But when I select another item in dropdown it shows as 0

Comment: Hmmmm will try. Request you to kindly look into in your spare time.

Comment: Its multiple selection dropdown. The logic code written in VBA code of the sheet.

Comment: You can select one item then again select one more item and so on.... But the summation code is not working yet

Comment: It seems to work now for me. Same file http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00724137915813781229

Comment: I downloaded your file but is dosen't count the duplicate items :( By the way I am very great full for your kind help. :)

Comment: Try the following. Delete the contents of cell B2. Then add Apple twice. I get 200 in D2 which is summing including the duplicates.