# Use of Array/VLOOKUP to create sums from lists

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vlookup

I'm using Excel 2007+, My plan is to create 3 connected columns, the first column is a basic description(text), to help you understand what i'm trying to do column 1 will be colours(so in the column "Red" would be a correct value to enter and this is simply typed in). Column 2 would be a modifier in the form of a list separated by commas in this example shapes and this is entered using a combination of Vlookup and VBA to call from a list in column A in the next sheet(so in this column "Triangle,Square,Circle").

Finally my problem is i want column 3 to be a sum of column 2 this would not be the sum of the shapes however, it would be the sum of values assigned to the shapes(this value would be right next to the shape in VLOOKUP list, B Column)

Hope my explanation helps, let me know if you need more info.
I have added an image for an example, where the left columns are lists to be looked up and the right is an example of what it would look like when correct.

Tried VLOOKUP but I'm missing something.

none yet

See image for expected results, the value column should auto-complete when the shape and colour columns have been filled.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjYTG.png

Comment: I do not have a complete solution but the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula might be helpful, as splitting the string, e.g. Triangle, Square ... into a vector will probably be part of the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560632/5632629