# How do I lookup multiple values from a comma separated cell and average the results in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a formula that can lookup multiple ISO country codes separated by comma contained in one cell (Cell A2, Image 1) with a reference to a list of country codes and education scoring (Columns F and G, Image 1). Then return the average of the scores of all countries on cell B2. does anyone know if I can build a formula to handle that?  [image]

Comment: With normal formulas,no. Your problem is that you need to split the text in each cell separated with commas, and also, you need to iterate each fragment, not a specific one, so you'll need VBA to do this, as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$2:F$34,A2)),G$2:G$34)/SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$2:F$34,A2)))`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you could do this with cell formula, but then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula) post and came up with this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNA(MATCH($F$2:$F$99, TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)))=1),99)), 0)), "",  $G$2:$G$99 ))
```

Try pasting  into cell `B2` as an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) and fill-down... And don't ask me how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim strCode As String, strScore As String
    Dim rngVlookup As Range
    Dim Code As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngVlookup = .Range("F2:G34")

        For i = 2 To 3

        strCode = ""
        strScore = ""

            strCode = .Range("A" & i).Value

            For Each Code In Split(strCode, ",")
                If strScore = "" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    strScore = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Trim(Code), rngVlookup, 2, False)
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    strScore = strScore & ", " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Trim(Code), rngVlookup, 2, False)
                End If

            Next Code

            With .Range("B" & i)
                .Value = strScore
                .NumberFormat = "0.000000"
            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```