# Excel 2013 - Multiple numbers in cell as text string, need to identify if any are less than certain value

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have been given a large amount of data (and can't go back and ask them to provide it in a more useful manner). It contains multiple figures in the same cell, separated by a semicolon.

```
  A
 +-------------------------+
1|Sats                     |
 +-------------------------+
2|92; 89; 94; 99; 100      |
 +-------------------------+
3|95; 98; 96               |
 +-------------------------+
4|99                       | 
 +-------------------------+
5|88; 95                   |
 +-------------------------+
6|99; 95; 98; 98; 100; 95  |
 +-------------------------+
7|94; 92; 91; 93           |
 +-------------------------+
```

Somehow, I need to identify whether or not a cell includes a number lower than 94. Just a yes/no, fortunately I don't need any greater analysis than that.

Or alternatively, to list the lowest number in each cell. Anything that can show if there's a number below 94.

Unfortunately, the number of different readings in each cell is unlimited - otherwise, I'd have nested formulae checking the first, second, third etc entry.

Does anyone have any ideas? This has completely stumped me.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Text to columns?

Comment: Should've said that I want to avoid text to columns if it's at all possible - I didn't make myself clear, the fact that the number of readings in each cell is unlimited means I can't just create some columns, I don't know how many to make. Could be over a hundred.

Comment: (1) The number of columns is irrelevant (2) If not TTC you'll need VBA.

Comment: Also, I was trying to figure out something on this basis: IF(LEFT([@Stat],((SEARCH(";",[@Stat])))-1),"Y" then using LEN(LEFT([@Stat],((SEARCH(";",[@Stat])))-1)) with MID to select the next number, and then repeating that for the next and so on... but I don't know if that can work with an unlimited string of numbers.

Comment: I'll try to figure out a VBA approach. Might end up asking another question about that, but I'll do my best to figure it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll probably want to use the split function to pass the contents to an array and then check if any instance of the array is greater than 94. You can find guidance on split here https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a crack at that.

Comment: I think I might delete this question. Not sure it's going to be of any benefit to other users. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @RolloTreadway See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865614/388606) for a formula as an alternative to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25316426/388606), you can use the below array formula (don't forget to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>!) in cell `B2` to return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` if your list of numbers contains a number less than `94`:

```
 =SUM(--(1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1)))=1),99))<94))>0
```

You can then just drag this down in column B and it should work, however, you may need to also replace the spaces between your delimiters `;` so it is one continuous list in each cell, e.g. `92;89;...`

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for! (Although I'm also going to try and learn the VBA split thing, because I think that'll be very helpful in future). It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

(Also, rather than replacing the space, I switched ";" to "; ".)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UDF for this.

create a new module in VBA (Alt +F11)

Then use the below code:

```
Public Function ParseAndSum(source As String) As Integer
       Dim tmp() As String, i As Integer
       tmp = Split(source, ";")
       For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
       ParseAndSum = Val(tmp(i)) < 94
       Next i
End Function
```

In B2 use the formula :

```
=ParseAndSum(H19)<0
```

If there is a value below 94 in there string within A2, it will return `TRUE`, else it will return `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use PowerQuery (assuming you are one 2013 or later). To do this select you data, go to Data>From Table/Range. The Power Query window will open. Go to Transform>Split Column>By Delimiter. You can trim the result to remove spaces by clicking on Format>Trim.

Comment: I am using 2013, but there's no PowerQuery, sorry.

Comment: @RolloTreadway It is available as a free download from Microsoft.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379 (but requies admin rights that you may not have if on a work computer)

Comment: I don't have admin rights. I'll have a word with IT, see what their position is.

Answer (score 0):

Put this column into C, then choose this column, use Data->Text to columns, and split by semicolon, this will split to D, E, F...

After that, at B column write =MIN(C1:Z1), or you can put more large cell number.

Then at A column write =IF(C1>94, "YES","NO"). then filter by A column.

Comment: I was hoping not to split into multiple columns, because I've no way of knowing how many columns will be required, and in same cases it'll be a few dozen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain you have the `FILTERXML` function in 2013.

You can use that to split the string, and then test it in the **array** formula:

```
=OR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")<94)
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]