# Create new list with multiple enteries based on value in cell

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

Main table contains names and number of appearance.
I need new list of names where every name will be repeated as many times as value in number of appearance cell.
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "MAIN LIST" is in A2:C7 (including headers), try the following **array** formula

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT($B$3:$B$7&"</s><s>",$C$3:$C$7))&"</s></t>","//s"),"")
```

*Note:* Clever idea from answer by @VafāSarmast [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula)

Comment: excel 2019 is required to use TEXTJOIN function. There is errors in function: need to replace every , with ; finction does not provide expected result. No new rows are added. I have tried to correct yours solution widhouth "</s><s>  := IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;REPT($B$3:$B$7;$C$3:$C$7))&"</s></t>";"//s");"") and got repeated names in same cell. But that is not what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of excel are you using? I tested it on 365

Comment: Are you entring the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter? It's an array formula

Comment: 2019 version, tried also with Ctrl+Shift+Enter but , error persist. Only when replase , with ; works but not as expected

Comment: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ir4lszXAoLp_BpvwCPcD4EshSek_w8XM

Comment: Its working. My lack of knowledge about arrays was a problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using JvdV's solution for this [Find row number of sum result in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454974/find-row-number-of-sum-result-in-range)

Assuming your names  are in column B and appearance in column C, use the following:
`=INDEX(B$1:B$7,MATCH(TRUE,--SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C$1:C$7,,,ROW(C$1:C$7)))>=ROWS($1:1);0)`

Enter as array formula (`ctrl + shift + enter`).

It returns the row number of the sum of values in column C that equals the number of rows used in your results list and shows the value in that row from column A.