# Find row number of sum result in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm breaking my head on the following:

I have `15` as a lookup value in `B1`

In `A1:A4` for each cell the value is `5`. (I  real these are all different values).

I want excel to SUM the values of `A1:A4` one by one and if the search value is reached by that sum, return the row number. So for this example I want result 3 (=5+5+5)
If no exact match then return the closest match smaller than the search value.

I tried something like `=MATCH(1,B1=SUM(A1:A4),1)`
which doesn't work obviously, but I don't know if it's even possible without VBA.
Does anybody know a way (without helper column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,--SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:A4,,,ROW(A1:A4)))>=B1,0)
```

I'm using Excel O365, but any other version may need CSE-entering of the above (I'm unsure). Do note `OFFSET()` is volatile!

The above would return the row where the cumulative sum first `>=B1`. If your goal as per your question was to get the closest match **but** smaller than `B1` in case there is no exact match:

```
=MATCH(B1,--SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:A4,,,ROW(A1:A4))))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And with Office 365 it's worth mentioning it can be accomplished using SCAN:

`=XMATCH(B1,SCAN(0,A1:A4,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),1)`