# How to determine the order of a substring in xls

Tags: excel

In xls I have a single cell with multiple arguments in text format like this:
`a;c;d;b`

I want a formula which tells me the order, so for Input

- `a` it should return `3`
- `c` it should return `2`
- `d` it should return `1`
- `b` it should return `0`

the substrings "a", "b" etc. have multiple letters.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all take the string value of the cell, then split it based on the semicolons. After that you have an array (or a list) of strings.
Then sort this list as you need.

I cannot figure out your sort order - it looks like you made it up.
So maybe you just need to assemble the strings from the list in your order, but that is what string concatenation should solve.

Comment: The order is given by the string. b is the last one so it gets 0.

Comment: Then simply count the number of semicolons after your string component. B has zero semicolons coming afterwards, but A has three of them.

Comment: This is what I want, can you provide a simple formula for that without using vba stuff?

Comment: Got it, it's in german '=LET(endString; RECHTS(A$1;LÄNGE(A$1)-SUCHEN(C2;A$1)); LÄNGE(endString)-LÄNGE(WECHSELN(endString;";";"")))'

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following on cell `D2`:

```
=LET(split, TEXTSPLIT($A$1,";"), cols, COLUMNS(split), 
 pos, SEQUENCE(1, cols, cols-1,-1), XLOOKUP(C2:C5, split, pos))
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

where the **Lookup** column have the input values for testing purpose. If you enter a letter that doesn't exist in cell `A1`, it returns `#N/A`.

### Explanation

`LET` function is used to avoid repetitions of the same calculations in the formula.

From your requirement it seems you want to return the position in **reverse order** starting from the number of letters minus `1` and ending in `0`.

`split` variable `TEXTSPLIT($A$1,";")` generates the following output (column wise):

```
a   c   d   b
```

The `cols` variable `COLUMNS(split)` calculates the number of columns of the `split` array. In our case `4`.

The `pos` variable represents the array positions and the output we are looking for, `SEQUENCE(1, cols, cols-1,-1)` would generate the following output:

```
3   2   1   0
```

and `XLOOKUP(C2:C5, split, pos)` generates the final result.

### Notes

If you don't have `TEXTSPLIT` available in your excel version, you can try instead:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Remember [FILTERXML](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) has also some constraints: *it is not available in Excel for the web and Excel for Mac*. Since the solution generates column-wise arrays, you need to transpose the output of `FILTERXML`, i.e. `TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML(...))`.

An alternative if you can't use `FILTERXML` is the following one. Adapted the response of the question: [Split a string (cell) in Excel without VBA (e.g. for array formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula) provided by: @Carble:

```
=LET(txt,A1,del, ";",length, LEN(txt)+1, 
items, length-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(txt,";","")),
seq, SEQUENCE(items,,0), findSpaces, FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(txt,del," ",seq)),
startTxt, IFERROR(findSpaces+1,1),startDel1, IFERROR(findSpaces,0),
startDel2, IFERROR(FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(txt,del," ",seq+1)), length),
MID(txt,startTxt,startDel2-startDel1-1)
)
```

If your version doesn't allow to use `LET`, then just replace the value of the variable defined in the formula. It will require `SEQUENCE` (available from O365 2021). Not having even `SEQUENCE` will make it very hard. A helper columns will be required to generate the sequences.

Comment: Looks promising, thank you! But Textsplit is available only in the beta yet. I have an education licence so I guess I can't upgrade it -.-

Comment: Next time you need to specify in the question your version constraints (there are specific excel version tags), so a specific solution can be provided. You can try `FILTERXML` but it doesn’t work for Excel for the Web, which is the version I have, so I cannot test it. Check [here](https://www.howtoexcel.org/split-text-by-delimiter/) how.

Comment: @s_b Updated the question to consider other Excel version scenarios. I hope it helps.