# How to return unique values listed in a row on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, horizontallist

I need to list all unique publications, which are listed horizontally:

- Publications | PUB-942575 | PUB-936976 | PUB-936976 | PUB-936976 | PUB-947197 | PUB-947197 | PUB-940212 | PUB-928798

I want to return only the unique values horizontally in a row, like below:

- Publications | PUB-942575 | PUB-936976 | PUB-947197 | PUB-940212 | PUB-928708

If the publications can be sorted alphabetically, that would be even better.

All the formulas I've found work for values listed vertically, so any help form the community would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  All of the answers proposed so far require functions from Excel O365.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `UNIQUE()` function should work for you like-

```
=UNIQUE(B1:I1,TRUE)
```

- Second `[by_col]`  parameter `TRUE` indicates to return unique by column. If you want to add word `Publication` then may try with `HSTACK()`.

  =HSTACK(A1,UNIQUE(B1:I1,1))

[image]

Comment: And actually, if they just used your `=UNIQUE()` formula as-is, but entered `=UNIQUE(A1:I1,TRUE)` the first unique cell would already be the "Publications" and no HSTACK is required!  They'd only need to use HSTACK() if they wanted to do the alphabetical sort:  `=HSTACK(A1,SORT(UNIQUE(B1:I1,TRUE),,,TRUE))`.

Comment: You did the work, I just tagged along ;)  If you want to just edit that into your answer with an explanation, I'll delete the comment and it'll be done.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your example if the input is a string delimited by `" | "` or a column delimiter. In your question there is no Excel version constraint so I am going to assume you can use `TEXTSPLIT` in case your input is a string delimited by `" | "`. If that is not the case, check this question: [Split a string (cell) in Excel without VBA (e.g. for array formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula) for other alternatives.

You can use `UNIQUE(array,[by_col])` with `by_col` input argument to select unique elements by columns.

Similarly you can use `SORT(array,[sort_index],[sort_order],[by_col])` and in a similar way to force sort by column using `by_col` input argument.

If we have the input argument on cell `A1` and you put the following formula in `C2`:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," | "), TRUE),,,TRUE)
```

Here is the output in column format returning an `1x5` array:

[image: sample excel file]

If you want the result as pipe delimited string, then on the previous result invoke `TEXTJOIN(delimiter, ignore_empty, text1, [text2], …)` as follow:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",,SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," | "), TRUE),,,TRUE))
```

and the output will be a single single string as follow:

```
PUB-928798 | PUB-936976 | PUB-940212 | PUB-942575 | PUB-947197
```

as you can see the result is sorted by ascending order.